# array.prototype function to logically OR elements

Tags: javascript

I tried this:

```
Array.prototype.mergeTrue = function(b) {
    // assume the arrays have same length
    this.forEach(function(val,i){
        this[i] = val || b[i];
        console.log(val || b[i], this[i]);
    });
}
var c = [false, true, false, true];
var d = [false, false, true, true];
c.mergeTrue(d);
console.log(c);
```

and got this result:
false false
true true
true true
true true
[ false, true, false, true ]

but expected this on the last line:
[ false, true, true, true ]

What am I missing?

Comment: `this` inside the forEach callback, refers to the `window` not the array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Description

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Array.prototype.mergeTrue = function(b) {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
        this[i] = this[i] || b[i];
    }   
}
var c = [false, true, false, true];
var d = [false, false, true, true];
c.mergeTrue(d);
console.log(c);
```